# wrong # args: should be "namespace subcommand ?arg ...?" while running nam

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ns2

I have installed NS2 allinone package in ubuntu and after the installation if i type ns in terminal it shows the desired "%" sign. However when i type nam then, it doesn't show the network animator window instead gives the erroe

```
nasif@nasif-HP-ProBook-440-G1:~$ ns
% nam
wrong # args: should be "namespace subcommand ?arg ...?"
```

what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

---

You cannot call nam from the 'ns' prompt ( % ).

Please open a new terminal session for nam : $ nam

... Then you will find out if you have a functional 'nam'. ( The Ubuntu nam package(s) cannot be used. A bug , March 2014, has not yet been solved.)

But sometimes the 'nam' from ns-allinone-2.35 is usable. Works when using ns-allinone-2.35**_gcc482**.tar.gz ( "Nov 2014 update" ) : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSGJCZ2YzUGJDVk0/view?usp=sharing

Else : Use [a tested package](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ns-stop-couldn't-execute-nam-permission-denied-while-executing-exec-nam-4175524760/#2) for *your* OS : Post #2 [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ns-stop-couldn't-execute-nam-permission-denied-while-executing-exec-nam-4175524760/#2) ...

---

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go though so much trouble to find an answer...
The link blow is a nam i tested it and it worked, i've uploaded it so people could easily use it.

Filesize: 2.620 MB
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08988171564893843065
Just copy it to your ns2 directory and use it...
Example :

`$cd ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/
 ~/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/$ ./ns ./simulation.tcl
 ~/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/$ ./nam ./out.nam`

And replace the `./nam` with your nam file that you downloaded.